# Android Studio Failed to resolve: .espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0

Tags: android, gradle

I try to sync my project, but it keeps failing with the following error messages :

Failed to resolve: androidx.{specific activity name here}.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0

Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Failed to resolve: androidx.{specific activity name here}.ext:junit:1.1.1

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example."
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner ".runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta8'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation '.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation '.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
}
```

Comment: have you tried invalidate & restart?

Comment: Yes, I have. But it didn't work.

Comment: try specifying full package of it `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'` and `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'`

Comment: Thanks, but it  is still erroneous.

Comment: hmmm, try specifying something in your applicationId e.g. `applicationId "com.example.mytestingproject"

Answer (score 0):

Do clean and build maybe or may not be sometime this type of error occurring